# Product of two foliations

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, foliations

1.What is  an example of  a manifold $M$ with two foliations $F$ and $F'$ which are not topological equivalent but the product foliations $F\times F$ and $F'\times F'$, as foliations on $M\times M$, are topological equivalents.

2.Assume that $F,F'$ are two foliations of manifolds $M,N$, respectively. How can one express $C^{*}(F\times F')$  in term of $C^{*}(F)$ and $C^{*}(F')$.

Note: The product foliation is simply the foliation obtained by cartesian product of leaves. By $C^{*}(F)$, I mean the $C^{*}$ algebra associated with foliation  $F$.

Comment: Am I missing something? For question 2, isn't it clear from the definitions that $C^*(F\times F')=C^*(F)\otimes C^*(F')$ (minimal tensor product)?. Think that, if the leaf spaces are Hausdorff, then $C^*(F)$ is Morita equivalent to $C_0(M/F)$, so $C^*(F\times F')$ is Morita equivalent to $C_0((M\times N)/(F\times F'))=C_0(M/F)\otimes C_0(N/F')$.

Comment: @AlainValette  Thank you very much for the comment. Are you considering "leaf space is Hausdorff" or "Holonomy groupoid is Hausdorff?

Comment: In particular is it clear that holomy groupoid of the product is the product of the holomomy groupoids?

Comment: @AlainValette I can understand your comments about fibered foliation but what about more complicated foliation?